# Make this regex work with all numbers even though there is no decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a script that get the negative percentage number between two numbers. since one number is dynamic and have different currencies, decimals etc I need a regex for that. It almost works, but the first two numbers only work if i add two decimals (.00) to the number. Why is this?

The output on all numbers should be 33.

Fiddle: **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/15/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    €1.000&nbsp;
    <span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span>
 </em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">
    1500
 </em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    1&nbsp;000:-&nbsp;
    <span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span>
 </em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">
    1500
 </em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    10,000.00SEK&nbsp;
    <span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span>
 </em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">
    15000
 </em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    SEK10,000.00&nbsp;
    <span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span>
 </em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">
    15000
 </em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.left').each(function() {
var frstCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price').text().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/[^0-9.]|\.(?=\d{3,})/g, "").replace(/(\.\d+)+/,''), 10);
var seCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""), 10);        
var result = 100 - (frstCol / seCol) * 100;
console.log("frstCol: ", frstCol, ", seCol: ", seCol);
$(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(parseInt(result)|| 0);
});
```

Comment: Have a read through [mcve]. If you're having an issue with a regular expression, rather than a wall of HTML and such, just show the regular expression, a sample of how you're using it, expecting inputs, and expected outputs, along with a statement of what outputs you're getting that vary from the expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because both of the `em` within `.left` have the same class, so you're picking up the text of both in `frstCol`. You should use `:first` to restrict the selector:

```
var frstCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price:first').text().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/[^0-9.]|\.(?=\d{3,})/g, "").replace(/(\.\d+)+/,''), 10);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/16/)

Also note that you can simplify your code slightly:

```
$('.left').each(function() {
    var frstCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price:first').text().trim().replace(/[^0-9.]|\.(?=\d{3,})/g, ""), 10);
    var seCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text().trim().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""), 10);
    var result = parseInt(100 - (frstCol / seCol) * 100, 10);
    $(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(result || 0);
});
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense - Im a bit embarrassed I didnt think about that :( You rock, thanks!